# How to hide left panel in jquery.mobile.splitview in desktop screen

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is about jquery.mobile.splitview 1.2

The normal behavior of jquery.mobile.splitview when display on the desktop is having the left panel with several menus. And right panel will display its content according to the left menu we select.

When we shrink the windows to the smaller size, it will hide all left panel and display top menu button instead.

What is the best way to set it to default to keeping the top menu button instead of display left panel menu. ?

Here current display:
[image]

Below when we shrink window, it will hide left panel and display menu

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I found a solution by changed the $window.width in jquery.mobile.splitview.js to make it larger and it worked.
Here what I did

```
 -        else if($window.width() < 768 && $window.width() > 480){
 +        else if($window.width() < 1280 && $window.width() > 480){
```

and

```
 -        else if($window.width() > 768){
 +        else if($window.width() > 1280){
```